# Hover sobre div afecta posición de elemento dentro de svg

Tags: html, css, svg, hover

Lo que necesito es que al hacer hover sobre mi "img" haga el efecto que ahora hace, pero solo lo he logrado que lo haga con hover sobre todo el div con la clase "FirstColumnBasic".

He intentado otros métodos pero éste es el que se acerca más a lo que necesito, si alguien pudiera apoyarme se lo agradecería bastante.

De antemano muchas gracias por su tiempo!

```css
img {
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#000;
}

.st3{fill:#B3D9D9;}

.st4{fill:#D6EBEB;}

.FirstColumnBasic #ejecutivo-boton {
  transform: translateY(0px); 
}

.FirstColumnBasic:hover #ejecutivo-boton {
  transform: translateY(-197px);
}
```

```html
<div class="FirstColumnBasic">

<img class="image">

<div id="svgwrapper" style="width:1400px;">

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1275 456" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1275 456;" xml:space="preserve">

<g id="movimiento">
 <rect id="linea-ejecutivo" x="632.5" y="-0.2" class="st3" width="10" height="235.9"/>

 
 <g id="ejecutivo-boton">
  <path class="st2" d="M649.4,225.7c0,4.7-4.1,8.5-9.2,8.5h-5.4c-5.1,0-9.2-3.8-9.2-8.5l-2.8-15.7c0-4.7,5.1-8.5,11.4-8.5h6.6
   c6.3,0,11.4,3.8,11.4,8.5L649.4,225.7z"/>
  <path class="st4" d="M626.9,209.8l2.8,15.6v0.4c0,2.5,2.3,4.5,5.1,4.5h5.4c2.8,0,5.1-2,5.1-4.5v-0.4l2.8-15.6
   c-0.2-2-3.2-4.2-7.3-4.2h-6.6C630,205.6,627.1,207.8,626.9,209.8 M640.2,238.3h-5.4c-7.2,0-13-5.4-13.2-12.2l-2.9-15.7v-0.4
   c0-7.1,6.8-12.6,15.5-12.6h6.6c8.7,0,15.5,5.5,15.5,12.6v0.4l-2.9,15.7C653.2,232.9,647.3,238.3,640.2,238.3"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>


</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

He borrado `style="width:1400px;"`de `#svgwrapper` porque quería ver lo que estoy haciendo. Puedes volver a ponerlo.

Si quieres que esto pase solo cuando pasas con el ratón por encima de la imagen puedes utilizar este css:

```
img:hover + #svgwrapper #ejecutivo-boton {
  transform: translateY(-197px);
}
```

Esto dice que cuando pasas con el ratón por encima de la imagen `img:hover` el `#ejecutivo-boton` situado dentro de `#svgwrapper` que a su turno es situado inmediatamente después de la imagen `img:hover + #svgwrapper #ejecutivo-boton {` sea trasladado en Y -197px

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
}

img:hover + #svgwrapper #ejecutivo-boton {
  transform: translateY(-197px);
}

.st3 {
  fill: #b3d9d9;
}

.st4 {
  fill: #d6ebeb;
}

.FirstColumnBasic #ejecutivo-boton {
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="FirstColumnBasic">

<img class="image">

<div id="svgwrapper">

<svg viewBox="0 0 1275 456">

<g id="movimiento">
 <rect id="linea-ejecutivo" x="632.5" y="-0.2" class="st3" width="10" height="235.9"/>

 
 <g id="ejecutivo-boton">
  <path class="st2" d="M649.4,225.7c0,4.7-4.1,8.5-9.2,8.5h-5.4c-5.1,0-9.2-3.8-9.2-8.5l-2.8-15.7c0-4.7,5.1-8.5,11.4-8.5h6.6
   c6.3,0,11.4,3.8,11.4,8.5L649.4,225.7z"/>
  <path class="st4" d="M626.9,209.8l2.8,15.6v0.4c0,2.5,2.3,4.5,5.1,4.5h5.4c2.8,0,5.1-2,5.1-4.5v-0.4l2.8-15.6
   c-0.2-2-3.2-4.2-7.3-4.2h-6.6C630,205.6,627.1,207.8,626.9,209.8 M640.2,238.3h-5.4c-7.2,0-13-5.4-13.2-12.2l-2.9-15.7v-0.4
   c0-7.1,6.8-12.6,15.5-12.6h6.6c8.7,0,15.5,5.5,15.5,12.6v0.4l-2.9,15.7C653.2,232.9,647.3,238.3,640.2,238.3"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>


</div>
</div>
```